# ng-src not displaying image from computer

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ng-source to display an image. According to properties in the image my filepath is correct. According to the properties my sourcefolder is C:\testImageFolder. And the images name is test.jpg so therefore the image source should be C:\testImageFolder\test.jpg but that image is not showing up, However if i use an image from online my image is showing.

HTML-

```
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="panel panel-info">

<div class="panel-heading">Attachment</div>
<!-- <div class="panel-body"> -->
<img ng-src="{{img_source}}">
```

js

```
      function imageModalController($scope, $http, employeeFactory, $modalInstance) {
$scope.getImageReturn = function() {
    $scope.img_source = "C:\testImageFolder\test.jpg";
    //data.path;
};
$scope.getImageReturn();
$scope.cancel = function() {

    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

$scope.signUp = function() {
    // alert("call signUp");
    window.location = "index.html#/signUp";
};

$scope.getImage = function(email) {

    employeeFactory.getImage(mail);

};
```

}

Comment: Have you ever seen something like `C:\testImageFolder\test.jpg` as an image path in the internet?

Comment: zerkms even if you were to do it as / instead if \ it still wouldnt work

Answer (score 1):

It's generally best to run angular against a local web server, but if you must display something directly from the filesystem, you need to use a filesystem URI:

```
$scope.img_source = "file:///c:/testImageFolder/test.jpg";
```

Comment: when doing that i get resource not allowed to be loaded